# Libgdx game freezing on stage.draw()

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm having a strange problem with my Libgdx game wherein it freezes when I call "stage.draw()". Strangely, this only occurs when I transition to the screen in question. For instance, I have two splash screens that come before this screen, and after they successfully complete it freezes on this screen. However, if this is the first screen to be shown, it runs fine.

**EDIT:** To clarify what I mean by freezing, it sits idly on a black screen and my mouse turns to a loading symbol until I click somewhere, at which point I get an actual Java pop-up letting me know that the "Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working". Event name: APPCRASH.

MenuScreen's render:

```
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
            super.render(delta);
            batch.begin();
            background.draw(batch);
            batch.end();
            stage.act(delta);
            stage.draw();
    }
```

AbstractScreen's render:

```
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
```

I've debugged it and can tell that it gets to STAGE.draw() and hangs. If I remove everything from the stage, this does not occur. The stage is setup as follows:

```
    @Override
    public void show() { 
            super.show();

            background = new Sprite(buildTexture(backgroundTextureNode));

            stage = new Stage();
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

            table = new Table();
            table.setFillParent(true);

            heading = buildLabel(headingNode);
            table.add(heading).spaceBottom(TITLE_SPACE);
            table.row();

            transitionButtons.addAll(buildTransitionButtons(transitionButtonNodes));

            for(final TextButton button : transitionButtons) {
                    table.add(button);
                    table.row();
            }

            stage.addActor(table);
    }
```

I thought that it may be something to do with the font, but I made a new label with the default font and it had the same problem.

**Edit:** Here's my thread dump: http://pastebin.com/JqB8fX85

**Edit:** I have Gdx logging each of my calls. Here's what I get:

SplashScreen: Constructor called
SplashScreen: Show called
SplashScreen: Transition in 7.0 seconds
SplashScreen: Resize called
TYR: Setting screen: SplashScreen
TYR: Creating
SplashScreen: Resize called
TYR: Resizing game to: 1920 x 1080
SplashScreen: Dispose called
SplashScreen: Constructor called
SplashScreen: Hide called
SplashScreen: Show called
SplashScreen: Transition in 7.0 seconds
SplashScreen: Resize called
TYR: Setting screen: SplashScreen
SplashScreen: Dispose called

**Update**
As mentioned, I have two screens that come before the menu screen that is freezing. When I comment out the sprite.draw(batch) line from those it makes it to the third screen. After further review, I noticed that during a tween callback event I call dispose. I commented this out to see if it was somehow causing a crash and sure enough it went all the way through.

Comment: Is an exception thrown?

Comment: No, it freezes until I click somewhere, at which point I get an actual Java pop-up letting me know that the "Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working". Event name: APPCRASH.

Here's my thread dump: http://pastebin.com/JqB8fX85

Comment: Are you re-using the same stage? You should not do that.

Comment: No, I am not using the same stage. I updated my code above for clarity.

Comment: The culprit is probably: _at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.nglDrawElements(Native Method)_ which causes a buffer overflow. As to why, I don't know. Are you using the latest LibGDX?

Comment: I believe so, yes. However, I am not completely sure how to update using the new Gradle build. I searched in the build.gradle file for "gdxVersion = ...", but it wasn't there.

Comment: maybe you run `show()` multiple times while `render()` is getting ran? which would keep resetting the stage with a new instance I don't know what that would do but might probably cause some latency issues.

Comment: I've added my logger calls to the bottom of my post. I don't believe show() is being called multiple times.